# With just the URL can we understand which hosting provider that website uses?

Tags: hosting

Our client forgot which hosting provider they have hosted their website. We got the IP of that with help of 'whatsmydns'. But with that information can we understand which is their hosting provider. They want to rebuild their website, and can't change their domain name.

Comment: Maybe they will remember the next time their hosting provider sends them their monthly bill.

Comment: Good one...:) But as most hosting companies take payment for 1 year, waiting such long is not a productive idea. _Technically, is there any option?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can't comment your question, and can't find whether we can send PM. Thus I'm writing this as an answer. I will delete it if it doesn't help.*

If they use their hosting provider as *registrar* for their domain name, they may find who it is using a *who is* service.

Example, using `dig`:

```
$ dig NS the-domain.name
;; QUESTION SECTION:
the-domain.name         IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
the-domain.name     1800    IN  NS  freedns4.registrar-servers.com.
the-domain.name     1800    IN  NS  freedns3.registrar-servers.com.
the-domain.name     1800    IN  NS  freedns5.registrar-servers.com.
the-domain.name     1800    IN  NS  freedns1.registrar-servers.com.
the-domain.name     1800    IN  NS  freedns2.registrar-servers.com.
```

Google (or a *who is* service) tells me that it belongs to NameCheap. *Perhaps* this could also be the hosting provider.

Comment: Great. Thank you. This sounds interesting.